# use word under cursor in cscope search

Tags: vim, command, shortcut, cscope

Is there a way to use the word under the cursor in a `cscope` search in Vim?
If the cursor is over a variable `Foo` and I want to avoid needing to type `Foo` again in the command line but would like to assemble `:cs f s Foo`.

Is there any way I can automate it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+word+under+cursor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use <kbd>CTRL-R</kbd> <kbd>CTRL-W</kbd> to copy the word under cursor to the command line:

```
:cs f s <C-R><C-W>
```

See the [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W) for more information.