# Is there a way to copy a word under the cursor and paste it in fzf line search in vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, fzf

I want to put a word under my cursor like `CACHED_VALUE`, and I want to put it in fzf line search `:Lines` or `:GFiles`, is there a way to achieve this?, because sometimes the variable name is big and difficult to type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use word under cursor in cscope search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56856357/use-word-under-cursor-in-cscope-search)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+copy+paste+word+under+cursor

Comment: @phd no, its pasting in `:` , but I want to paste in the floating window inside vi

Comment: @phd yes, that one has the answer, but i didn't grasp at first, thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `CTRL+R` `CTRL+W` will insert the word under the cursor.

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/628865/4333941

Comment: do you know fzf line search, ever used that?

Comment: ok, understood, `nnoremap <silent><space>lw :Lines <C-R><C-W><cr>
` does the job, thanks